# Getting an error in my app during an asyncTask while leaving my app

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have activity A and B. Both of them have AsyncTasks that connect to the web and fetch some JSON. I get an error that I can't quite replicate always, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I get the error when I press the back button from activity B to A to Homescreen.

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mycompany.myapp.ActivityGD$GetMethod.doInBackground(ActivityGD.java:131)
at com.mycompany.myapp.ActivityGD$GetMethod.doInBackground(ActivityGD.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
... 4 more
```

I have no idea how I could be getting a null pointer, on what seems like an AsyncTask. Note: ActivityGD = Activity B. So in esence, I don't understand how I'm getting a null pointer on Activity B when I simply pressed back on Activity A.

Lines 130 to 137

```
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        String[] myText = final.split(",");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                ActivityGD.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                myText);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: While your `AsyncTask` running on `ActivityGD` you press "BACK" means finish the `Activity` and all its properties including variables and objects. So your `AsyncTask` keep accessing those objects causing `NPE`. Make sure you stop `AsyncTask` before leaving `ActivityGD`, you can do that inside `onPause`. just `your_async_task.cancel(true);` should do the job. Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm! It's good to cancel/stop an asyncTask while you're leaving an activity?

Comment: Please post the code around ActivityGD.java:131

Comment: Posted in original question.

Comment: In your code. 'final' stands for?

Comment: final is a String object.

Comment: 'final' is a KEYWORD. Consider renaming it and make sure it's not null here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable, final, in line 131, is returning null and triggering the NPE. Probably because of exiting activity B while the asynctask is still running. Add a null check for it and that should take care of the NPE.